# Django links on base template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

- Django 1.5.1
- Experience, getting started

I'm currently working on my static side of the site.
And creating the HTML/CSS/JS stuff. In the base html i have some links. 
One of them is "about" that will lead to the ***...:8000/about***
Now when im on the about page there are the same links cause they are in the base template.
When i click on them now i get ***...:8000/about/about***
and it will go on adding the /about each time i click.

How should i get this link to always point to ***...:8000/about***

Thank you.

Comment: Also never hard code the urls, instead use [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolute URLs.. start your links with `/`

`<a href="/about/">` instead of `<a href="about/">`

Also, if it will "add /about" each time you click, that means you're re-rendering your view... which means your URLConf probably has a too-broad regex (make sure your line is terminated by a `/$`

Kind of sounds like you have a line like `url(r'^about/', 'foo')` where /about/about/about will continue to match.

---

It's also best practice to use the `{% url %}` tag via named urls. Sooner or later you'll change a URL and thank everyone for it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: Also always use the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Absolutely! :) You got my +1

Comment: Haha, added it. It's getting busy up there.

Comment: You guys are great!
added this to urls
  url(r'^about/$', 'mainsite.views.about'),
and then changed my link to 
<a href="{% url "mainsite.views.about"%}">אודות האתר</a> 

Thanks

Comment: @Trostik, last alternative is to "name" them which is typically the cleanest. `url(r'...', 'foo', name='my-link') {% url 'my-link' %}` That way, your templates are decoupled from python code, structure, etc. as much as possible. You can change the URL, assign the name to something else, etc., and your templates won't break.